# Android horizontal RecycleView with never-ending scroll animation

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation

I'm trying to implement an horizontal RecycleView in my Android app that displays content with never-ending scroll animation. [See example of required UI here](https://s7.gifyu.com/images/ezgif.com-video-to-gif008119f5e3c210b1.gif).

My question is, what would be the best practice on how to achieve this goal? (RecycleView should support scroll gestures from the user).

Comment: Should the content repeat itself from beginning if the animation reaches the content end? I think this would be a more elegant solution than the one showing in the gif. Make animation jumps to a position is not smooth UX.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correct you're looking for the endless scrolling or infinite scrolling (*Not Official names for that*)

If it is correct then it shows like say you have 5 images in your recyclerview now when the user reaches the end item then the recycler view starts again from the first item like

item1, item2, item3, item4, item5 and again item5, item1, item2.....

To achieve this

Go to your adapter class and do the following code.

```
@Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items == null ? 0 : items.size() * 2; //Here instead of items.size(); you have to change like this
    }
```

Now in your `OnBindViewHolder` method

```
MODEL_CLASS item = items.get(position%items.size());
```

Now head over to the activity where you set the adapter to recyclerview and add the following code

```
YOUR_ADAPTER_NAME.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                int firstItemVisible = linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
                if (firstItemVisible != 0 && firstItemVisible % YOUR_LIST_ITEM.size() == 0) {
                    recyclerView.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(0);
                }
            }
        });
```

By this you can see the items when scrolled to right it continues loops in your list.

Comment: the most important part for me is the animation, how to implement it.. there is no reference to the animation at all in your answer..

Comment: But there isn't any animation effect I found in that image. I can see you're just sliding the image slowly. If there's any animation effect please elucidate it I'll try to answer

Comment: @OdedRegev use "recyclerView.getLayoutManager().smoothScrollToPosition(recyclerView,RecyclerView.State(),0);" for smoother scrolling..